# Facebook like iframe cut with Joomla 3 bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, facebook-like, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

In my joomla 3 extension I'm displaying a facebook like button. If the user clicks on the like button the iframe which should show the comment box is cut and only a small part of it is visible.
Im not doing something special.

```
<div class="pull-left event-button">
    <div class="dp-share-button"><div id="fb-root"></div
        <fb:like href="http://joomla.digital-peak.com/demo/dpc/en" layout="button_count" show_faces="true" send="true" width="" action="like" font="arial" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>
    </div>
</div>
```

A demo can be found here http://joomla.digital-peak.com/demo/dpc/en click on the like button. I was searching the web up and down and I'm going crazy because I can't find a way to fix it. If somebody can help I really appreciate!!

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it because I don't use Facebook but from the markup and if the question is the overflow attribute, you can try adding the following jQuery script to your calendar script:

```
<script>
(function($){
    $(document ).ready(function(){
        $(".dp-share-button" ).find("iframe").css("overflow","visible");
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

At the end I think with this sample jQuery script you have a tool to test different css attributes and perhaps get to the best solution.
Probably you'll need some kind of trigger like a `$("yourbutton").bind("click", function(){ // your css modification code inside here });`

Comment: I tried various overflow settings and played around with many other css modifications...nothing worked

Comment: On the css modifications have you added the !important after the attribute value. Sometimes is a needed workaround to override any other css styles that are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too, just force the margin and padding to zero, set a max-height and max-width, this will solve for most users but still on some devices it will randomly load wrong.